# Restrict Product Variables Selection Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This relates to WooCommerce Product Variations.

A client has only one product (a cushion), it has one attribute (fabric type) with many variations - over 50 fabric type swatches.  They would like to display the fabric variations sorted into groups to make them easier for customers to choose from (example:  floral fabrics, baby fabrics, block colour fabrics).

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about WooCommerce Variable products type or about product variables which is something very different (and very vague). WC Variable product type are maid with attributes (for variations)… each attribute has some terms set in the product. Once this has been set, you generated Product variations… You should correct your question and try to be a little more precise. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Loic - I've made it more specific but have gotten a reply from WooCommerce in the mean time saying that it is not possible.  Thank you for your help though.